# RODBC - Column Name with Space

Tags: sql, r, quotes, netezza, rodbc

I'm trying to execute the following sql (Netezza) query in R

```
df <- sqlQuery(con, 'SELECT "ID", "Job ID", "Job Status" FROM DB1.EUL."Job Order"
            WHERE "Job ID" = 'JBNT00000888'', as.is=TRUE)
```

But it gives errors out:

> ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect

Is there any other way to pass the string through?

Comment: Tried with two single quotes but it did not work. `Error: unexpected string constant in:`

Comment: Try backticks `\`my col\`` or square brackets: `[my col]`.

Comment: I tried with backticks and it returned the same error as before. This is for Netezza which identifies columns as `"my col"` instead of `[my col]`.